# Watir-Webdriver, can click element in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="brands brands-search-region">
    <section class="module">
        <div class="listing">
            <article id="" class="node node-brand brand brand-item clickable multiple-item" about="/node/85531" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">
                <a href="/node/85531">
                </a>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I can click on the article element in chrome but not in firefox using:

```
browser.div(class: 'brands-search-region').article.click
```

I know I can do:

```
browser.div(class: 'brands-search-region').article.a.click that works in both but why does the previous not work in firefox?
```

I am using watir-webdriver with latest version of firefox, chromedriver and selenium-webdriver

Comment: You're using FF36?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Yep firefox 36.0.4. There's no error, It just moves on to the next line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different behaviour is due to how the FirefoxDriver implemented the clicking of an element compared to ChromeDriver. Based on my past observations:

- Chrome determines the centre of the element and then clicks the deepest element at those coordinates.
- Firefox determines the centre of the element and then clicks the centre of the element.

In other words, Firefox is clicking the article element. The click event only bubbles up, which means that the inner link never receives a click. In contrast, Chrome's algorithm will result in the link element being clicked first.

You can see the different behaviour in the following page. When elements that receive a click event will display an alert.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function highlight(elem) {
        alert(elem.nodeName);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="brands brands-search-region">
      <section class="module" onclick="highlight(this);">
        <div class="listing" onclick="highlight(this);">
          <article onclick="highlight(this);" style="border:1px solid red; text-align:center;">
            <a href="" style="border:1px solid green;" onclick="highlight(this);">asdf</a>
          </article>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Run the following script using Chrome and Firefox:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox # or :chrome
browser.goto 'path/to/file/test.htm'

browser.div(class: 'brands-search-region').article.click

bubbling = []
while browser.alert.exists?
    bubbling << browser.alert.text
    browser.alert.ok
    sleep(1)
end
p bubbling
```

In Chrome, the `bubbling` will be:

```
["A", "ARTICLE", "DIV", "SECTION"]
```

In Firefox, the `bubbling` will be:

```
["ARTICLE", "DIV", "SECTION"]
```

Firefox has started the click event at the element you told it to click - ie the article element. In contrast, Chrome clicks like a user would - ie at the deepest element at a specific coordinate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Justin. Appreciate it.